# How to implement save/cancel button in SPFx edit form customizer?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx, list-form, react

I built a Form Customizer for a SharePoint list, the UI and the logic works fine, but I don't know, how can I implement the Save/Cancel Method. I need only the Editform.

How can I call from the SharePoint list this custom form?

Thanks for any Help, have a good day!

Comment: check [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-form-customizer) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPvNR2nP2Xk) which explains how to create a form customizer and add save/cancel buttons on the form. Let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions like below in SPFx form customizer to save list form:

In render method:

```
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', this._onSave.bind(this));
```

Save function:

```
private _onSave = async (): Promise<void> => {
  // disable all input elements while we're saving the item
  this.domElement.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(el => el.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'));
  // reset previous error message if any
  this.domElement.querySelector(`.${styles.error}`).innerHTML = '';

  let request: Promise<SPHttpClientResponse>;
  const title: string = (document.getElementById('title') as HTMLInputElement).value;

  switch (this.displayMode) {
    case FormDisplayMode.New:
      request = this._createItem(title);
      break;
    case FormDisplayMode.Edit:
      request = this._updateItem(title);
  }

  const res: SPHttpClientResponse = await request;

  if (res.ok) {
    // You MUST call this.formSaved() after you save the form.
    this.formSaved();
  }
  else {
    const error: { error: { message: string } } = await res.json();

    this.domElement.querySelector(`.${styles.error}`).innerHTML = `An error has occurred while saving the item. Please try again. Error: ${error.error.message}`;
    this.domElement.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(el => el.removeAttribute('disabled'));
  }
}

private _createItem(title: string): Promise<SPHttpClientResponse> {
  return this.context.spHttpClient
    .post(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + `/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('${this.context.list.title}')/items`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json;odata.metadata=none'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        Title: title
      })
    });
}

private _updateItem(title: string): Promise<SPHttpClientResponse> {
  return this.context.spHttpClient
    .post(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + `/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('${this.context.list.title}')/items(${this.context.itemId})`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json;odata.metadata=none',
        'if-match': this._etag,
        'x-http-method': 'MERGE'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        Title: title
      })
    });
}
```

Follow this Microsoft official documentation for detailed steps: [Build your first Form Customizer extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-form-customizer)

Also, check this video for detailed walkthrough about - [How to create custom list forms with SharePoint Framework](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPvNR2nP2Xk)